# Unable to list labels in TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, tfs

We recently migrated to TFS2012, but are still using VS2008. Everything is working fine except for labels. It appears that applying labels works, and using a label when getting source works. However, listing labels returns nothing.

For example:

```
tf label "LabelName" *.* /r
```

will return "Created label LabelName@$/Scope"

If this is followed immediately with

```
tf labels /owner:*
```

the result is "No labels found"

Finally, trying to retrieve the label works correctly.

```
tf get . /version:L"LabelName"
```

will return the expected version of the files, and

```
tf label /delete "LabelName"
```

returns "Deleted label LabelName@$/Scope"

VS2012 is installed on the machine, but we haven't "officially" upgraded, and the behavior is the same. Listing labels from the IDE of both VS2008 and VS2012 shows no labels as well.

Anyone else experience anything similar? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `/owner:*` isn't documented in MSDN, does it take a wildcard?

Comment: Yes, the /owner switch can accept wildcards. This command will show all labels, regardless who the lable was created by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After futher trial and error, I've found that the @scope option isn't optional. If I create the label like this -

```
tf label LabelName@$/Server/Path *.* /r
```

I am able to see the label when issuing the tf labels command. When using the label in other commands, it can be referenced simply as LabelName, the @scope doesn't seem to be required.