# Unable to find TFS 2012 labels in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

This has never worked for me in VS2012. I can right click a folder in Source Control Explorer, select "Advanced -> Apply Label..." and enter a name. TFS plugs away, and the Output window states that the label has been created. Everything seems fine.

However, any attempt to find the label fails. Immediately after applying the label, I can right click the same folder and select "Find -> Find Label..." and I get nothing. I can search All Projects - nothing. I can search by Owner - nothing. I can even enter the label name - nothing.

Using the command line is no better. I go to the mapped folder which was just labeled, and "tf labels [any and all options]" always returns 'No labels found'.

BUT using the label works. If I specify the label name in either VS2012 when getting a specific version, or from the command line 'tf get /v:L'lable name' TFS is happy to comply.

It's obvious the label is in fact being created, and it can be used, but how can I list available labels?

Comment: I guess I've asked this before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523835/unable-to-list-labels-in-tfs2012. Slightly different situation, but same general problem.

Comment: Whilst I don't know the answer to your question. You can try TFS Sidekicks. The label sidekick will find your label. I've never encountered anything that TFS sidekicks wasn't able to find. http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2013

Comment: @SuitedAces - I'm sure that Sidekicks would probably work. Unfortunately, it isn't approved for use in our organization. :(

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

- Right click branch/project in Source code explorer.
- Choose History.
- At the top there should be two tabs "Changesets" and "Labels".

My "find label" does work in VS2012. I can't seem to find any labels in VS2008!